# Cross Domain cookie

Tags: firefox, cookies, dns, cors

I wrote an HTML page deployed in a Nginx web server which has server name **https://xxx.mario.com**

Inside the HTML I wrote a JS which makes an HTTP POST to **https://yyy.luigi.com/rest/api**

The api sets a cookie **testCookie** on domain **luigi.com**.

I saw the **testCookie** in http response header which has:

- path: /
- domain: luigi.com
- sameSite: none
- secure: true
- value: 9999999999999

but it is not stored in browser.

Is it possibile to store it in the browser?
The only way it works **is to enable "Third party cookie" in Firefox** (Browser Privacy -> Custom protection); with Firefox standard protection (Firefox 116.0.2) the cookie is not stored.

Do you confirm?